# Unable to read from Firebase using the handleResult() method for a QR Code Scanner

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, qr-code, zxing

I want the variables one, two and three to be able to read from my database when I scan the QR Code but I cant get them to display in the Builder.setMessage() line... I have tried calling the displayDeals() method in several places but none work...

```
package com.example.darren.offerapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class PopUpPage extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private String dealID;
    private Deals_Information deals_information;
    private String one = "";
    private String two = "";
    private String three = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up_page);

        //stuff for popup window
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int width = dm.widthPixels;
            int height = dm.heightPixels;
            getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*0.8), (int)(height*0.6));

        //calling the method which will pull the deals from the database
        //displaySuggestion();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dealID = firebaseUser.getUid();

        displayDeals();
    }

    public void displayDeals(){

        databaseReference.child("FruitDeals").child(dealID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                deals_information = dataSnapshot.getValue(Deals_Information.class);
                one = deals_information.getDeal();
                two = deals_information.getPrice();
                three = deals_information.getAisleNum();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        //do anything with result here
        Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Your Deal");
        builder.setMessage("Offer: " + one + "\r\n\r\nPrice: " + two + "\r\n\r\nAisle Number: " + three + "");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        //resume scanning
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this); //uncomment out this line when you want to scan again
    }
}
```

The Deals_Information class is here:

```
package com.example.darren.offerapp;
```

public class Deals_Information {

```
private String deal;
private String price;
private String aisleNum;


//getters and setters
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getAisleNum() {
    return aisleNum;
}

public void setAisleNum(String aisleNum) {
    this.aisleNum = aisleNum;
}

public String getDeal() {
    return deal;
}

public void setDeal(String deal) {
    this.deal = deal;
}

public Deals_Information(){

}

public Deals_Information(String deal, String price, String aisleNum)
{
    this.deal = deal;
    this.price = price;
    this.aisleNum = aisleNum;
}
```

}

[This is the image I am talking about in my last comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZSqS.jpg)

Comment: Don't ignore `onCancelled`. Implement it as `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }` to ensure you're not hiding errors.

Comment: Thanks Frank. This does not solve the problem of the data not displaying though. Have you any idea why this may be? Thanks dmq95

Comment: If the app doesn't crash now, you know that at least it's not (yet) a permission error. If none of your `onChild...` methods are getting called, you are most likely attaching the listener to the wrong location in the JSON tree.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have found the issue but cannot seem to rectify it. The variable dealID is pulling back the ID for the user (circled in the image below) when in fact I need it to return the key of the deal (as highlighted in the image below). Do you know how I would do this? I have tried getKey() but this wouldn't work either. Thanks in advance